# Drawing on a Button behind text C#

Tags: c#, .net, button, graphics

I want to draw onto a button whenever the mouse enters it. I want the rectangle to be drawn behind the buttons text. I have the following code to draw onto it:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = this.button1.CreateGraphics();
    LinearGradientBrush myBrush = new
        LinearGradientBrush(
        this.button1.ClientRectangle,
        Color.Red, 
        Color.AliceBlue, 
        LinearGradientMode.Horizontal
    );
    g.FillRectangle(myBrush, this.button1.ClientRectangle);
}
```

I was wondering how to do it, if it was possible without making a custom button.

If anyone has any suggestions/solutions, please post them here.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to draw the same thing on all buttons? Or do you want to draw a different thing on each button?

Comment: I would like to draw the same thing for every button on the form.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to make a custom button class, that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Button`. Why are you against that idea?

Comment: @Ove The reason I'm not using a custom button is because I have already made an application and was wondering if I could apply this to the buttons but it is not that important that I would re-write half of the application.

Comment: If you want to apply this to all the buttons in your application, then you would have to do the same number of modifications anyway. You can add a MouseEnter handler to every button in your application, or you can change all your buttons to custom buttons. In my opinion, creating a custom button is the easiest solution in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create a custom button, and override its `OnPaint` method to do the drawing. Then you can replace `Button` with `CustomBtn` in your source files and use the new button.

```
class CustomBtn : Button
{
    private bool ShouldDraw = false;
    private LinearGradientBrush myBrush = null;

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        ShouldDraw = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        ShouldDraw = false;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        if (ShouldDraw)
        {
            if (myBrush == null || (myBrush != null && myBrush.Rectangle != ClientRectangle))
            {
                myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush( ClientRectangle, Color.Red, Color.AliceBlue, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal );
            }
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, ClientRectangle);
            TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(pevent.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, ForeColor, flags);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will apply this to my application.